# GET request not working in android app

Tags: android, proxy, get

I am sending a GET request from my app, and on the phone I do not get the response, and it does not appear on my feed, however, if I copy paste the url on the browser, I can see the text that is supposed to appear.

For that, I installed BURP Proxy Suite to see what am I sending and receiving to and from the server, and below is the response that showed in Burp.

```
GET /?feed=rss2&tag1=mytagone&tag2=mytagtwo HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: want to share your code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

> first open the connection as OPEN and run it and if wont works again run the >code change the USER-AGENT